# Запятая перед и в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

К тому же проезжая часть дороги очень узкая и разъехаться машинам не предоставляется возможным. Нужна ли запятая перед и.

Comment: опечатка в слове представляется ("о" не нужно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно ли написать так:
К тому же ... разъехаться машинам не предоставляется возможным. 
Получается коряво. Потому что, мне кажется, вторая часть предложения вытекает из первой, т. е. первая - причина, вторая - следствие. И, как вывод, слова *к тому же* здесь не являются общими.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Вопрос был, нужна ли запятая в исходном предложении, а вы предлагаете вариант правки.

Comment: Да, а в отношении "к тому же" тоже непонятно, почему слова не общие? См. ответ Vera - и комментарии к нему.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая перед  союзом И в ССП не ставится, так как присоединительный союз К ТОМУ ЖЕ является общим для двух предложений.

Comment: Я тоже так считала, но сомневалась со словом к тому же. Я думала, что только общее обстоятельство влияет на постановку запятой.

Comment: Общие элементы могут быть разными (обстоятельство, вводное слово, общее придаточное, бессоюзная связь, общая вопросительная или восклицательная интонация), например: Между тем луна начала одеваться тучами и на море поднялся туман. По-видимому, он был в большом затруднении и в душе его совершалась борьба. Уже рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я возвратился в комнату. Через час явилась возможность ехать: метель утихла и небо прояснилось. Кто вы такие и что вам надобно? Как тихо вокруг и как чисто звёздное небо!

Comment: А мне кажется, что "последовательная" причинная связь между "проезжая часть узкая" и "машинам не разъехаться" здесь сильнее объединяющих "параллельно" свойств вводного элемента: союз "и" без изменения смысла заменяется здесь на "так что", "поэтому" и пр. Эта связь прямая и однозначная, она сильнее, чем в примере "рассвело и народ стал подниматься", где речь просто о сопутствующих одно другому явлений.

Comment: Уважаемые коллеги, понимаю ваше желание  оспорить ответ, но попробую всё-таки защитить его. Конечно, для окончательного решения нужен контекст, но я могу предположить, что до этого излагался какой-то важный довод, а затем автор решил "добавить" убедительности еще одним фактом. И этот факт описывается ДВУМЯ взаимосвязанными предложениями и присоединяется союзом К ТОМУ ЖЕ. Вообще же говоря, надо заметить, что общий элемент  обычно всегда обсуждается с большей страстью, чем он этого заслуживает. Мне кажется, что в этой теме надо давать составителям текста хотя бы немного авторской свободы.

Comment: Дорогие друзья, спасибо за единодушную коллективную  оценку всего лишь скромного частного мнения.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет общей части. "К тому же" относится только к первой основе. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Нужен контекст, чтобы понять,  относится союз только к первой части или ко всему предложению.